# My code to retrieve images through Firebase database URL doesn't work. What's wrong with the code?

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I have manually uploaded images to Firebase Storage and manually addad their respective URL to Firebase Database. I would now like to retrieve the images (one at at time) through this code, but it doesn't work. I would like to use this type of code, no alternative code.

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: self.recipeClassArray[self.currentView].recipeImageObject)!)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data,
            response, error -> Void in
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response))")
            print(error.debugDescription)
            if(error != nil)
            {
                return
            }
            self.recipeImageUI.image = UIImage(data: data!)

        })
```

`self.recipeClassArray[self.currentView].recipeImageObject` is the URL for the picture. I then set `self.recipeImageUI.image` (the imageView box in the UI) to the data. When I run the simulator I get no error message, but the image doesn't show. I have tried printing `self.recipeClassArray[self.currentView].recipeImageObject` in the console, and it gives a URL that does work if I copy past it into a browser (it shows the image). The console does say that [Boring SSL] ... sct extension length is less than sct data length. Any ideas?

Comment: When you print data what is your message on the log console ?

Comment: If you want to download the images you'll also have to worry about caching them. Rather than do all of that I recommend you take a look at KingFisher instead it's a super simple pod that you can use to download and cache your images. https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher code is something like let url = URL(string: "example.com")!
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url). https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet

Comment: @ Arrabidas92: I just get a URL that works perfectly if copied to a browser... Yeah, I've been looking into KingFisher and will probably use that :) Does that mean that I don't need the code above - just the two lines from KF? :) That would be awesome! Still, would like to know what's wrong with the code...